# JTextArea append doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea` and I would like to write message into the text area from another class by calling method `append(..)`. However the text area never updated.

I have tried two different solutions and didn't work.

```
public void setTextArea(String message) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jTextArea1.append(message);
        }
    } );

    jTextArea1.append(message);
    jTextArea1.setVisible(true);
    jTextArea1.repaint();
    jTextArea1.validate();

    System.out.print(message);      
}
```

Comment: At a guess, the likely cause is, the `JTextArea` you're trying to update isn't the `JTextArea` on the screen

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `jTextArea1.setVisible(true);` it is likely this text area should be visible (but empty) from the start. `jTextArea1.repaint();
    jTextArea1.validate();` sometimes that is called for **on the parent container** but would achieve nothing when called on the text area itself. It seems you're trying to code using bits and pieces of code that you found on the internet but do not understand.